# Doctrine entity with namespace within a bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use symfony3. Have the only bundle - `AppBundle`. I use yml for annotation. They live in AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine. If I want a new entity - I create new `.orm.yml` file and then run `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`. Everything works fine.

Once I needed another namespace for my entity. So I created a folder `Filter` in `doctrine` folder. And put a `Category` entity there. And then called a 'generate' command. I had an error `No mapping file found named 'Category.orm.yml' for class 'AppBundle\Entity\Filter\Category'.` Then removed `Filter` folder and recall the command. And everything worked fine. So the issue is in an additional folder. I tried to place `Category` just in `doctrine` folder but keep namespace in `yml` file (AppBundle\Entity\Filter\Category). That does not work.

So the **question** is: how to create an annotation for an antity with a parent namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it using the `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity` command:

> The Entity shortcut name: **AppBundle:Filter/Category**

This is how your project structure would be generated. No subdirectory in the doctrine directory, but instead the namespace in the YAML filename along:

```
src/
└── AppBundle/
    ├── Entity/
    │   ├── Filter/
    │   │   └── Category.php
    │   └── SomeEntity.php
    └── Resources/
        └── config/
            └── doctrine/
                ├── Filter.Category.orm.yml
                └── SomeEntity.orm.yml
```

Comment: Works! So no subdirectory, just point as a namespace separation?